# Why is asterisk executing the wrong hangup?

Tags: asterisk

```
[contextall]

include => context5xx
include => context8xx

[context5xx]

exten => _5xx,1,Verbose(3,Call in context5xx)
same => n,Hangup()

exten => h,1,Verbose(3,Executing hangup in 5xx)


[context8xx]

exten => _8xx,1,Verbose(3,Call in context5xx)
same => n,Hangup()

exten => h,1,Verbose(3,Executing hangup in 8xx)
```

When I call any extension in `5xx` series, it executes `5xx` hangup priorities and call is disconnected which is intended.

But when I call any extension in `8xx` series it *again* executes `5xx` hangup priorities and the call is disconnected, while I want to execute the hangup priority of the same context i.e. `context8xx`

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you not understand how include works.

All above is same as following:

```
[contextall]

exten => _5xx,1,Verbose(3,Call in context5xx)
same => n,Hangup()
exten => _8xx,1,Verbose(3,Call in context5xx)
same => n,Hangup()

exten => h,1,Verbose(3,Executing hangup in 5xx)

exten => h,1,Verbose(3,Executing hangup in 8xx)
```

So yes, it will execute first included h-extension.
If you want it work as you describe you have start it with goto

```
[context8xx]

exten => _8xx,1,Goto(${EXTEN},2)
same => n,Verbose(3,Call in context5xx)
same => n,Hangup()

exten => h,1,Verbose(3,Executing hangup in 8xx)
```

But really correct way - rewrite dialplan to be asterisk-way. You just thinking wrong way.

Comment: corrected it to use goto and its working as expected........


Thanks for your help

Regards.